# Why does my SSIS package takes so long to execute?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I am fairly new creating SSIS packages. I have the following SQL Server 2008 table called BanqueDetailHistoryRef containing 10,922,583 rows.

I want to extract the rows that were inserted on a specific date (or dates) and insert them on a table on another server. I am trying to achieve this through a SSIS which diagram looks like this:

`OLEDB Source (the table with the 10Million+ records) --> Lookup --> OLEDB Destination`

On the look up I have set:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now, the query (specified on the Lookup transformation):

> SELECT * FROM BanqueDetailHistoryRef WHERE ValueDate =  '2014-01-06';

Takes around 1 second to run through SQL Server Management Studio, but the described SSIS package is taking really long time to run (like an hour).

Why is causing this? Is this the right way to achieve my desired results?

Comment: Do you need every column from `BanqueDetailHistoryRef`?

Comment: Yes, I need all te columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show how your OLEDB Source component was set up but looking at the table names I'd guess you are loading the whole 10 million rows in the OLEDB source and then using the Lookup to filter out only the ones you need. This is needlessly slow.

You can remove the Lookup completely and filter the rows in OLEDB source using the same query you had in the Lookup.